# How to get event.preventDefault() working in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, preventdefault

In multiple different React.js projects I have going, I simply cannot get the preventDefault event listener to work. It keeps re-rendering the whole page.

I've tried changing the button type, I've tried using onClick rather than onSubmit, and I've tried other methods than preventDefault like return false and stopPropagation and so on.

```
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.props.createBox(this.state);
            this.setState({
                height: '',
                width: '',
                color: ''
            });
            }
```

and here's the button

```
    <button type='submit' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Create 
        Box!</button>
```

Comment: the screen renders again because you setState, event.preventDefault() works fine imo

Comment: This is working exactly how it should. Prevent default is working but a change of state rerenders the component

Comment: I removed the setState and it still is rerenders. The inputs correctly register the values i type, but the onSubmit rerenders the page and the new url lists the values from the inputs, without creating the new box.

Comment: Any changes to state will call the render method. All you would be doing is preventing the default behavior of the event you are subscribing to. Also, `this.props.createBox` very well seems like it could be modifying the state of the parent React Component. Since that component passes your child component props, your component would re-render because the parent component is re-rendering.